# Java GAE Memcache Exception (Standard Environment)

Tags: java, google-app-engine

We are using java based gae standard environment. Today we have received sudden surge of below memcache errors and subsequent appengine log

Memcache Error Message:

> Caused by: com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceException:
>   Memcache put: Error setting single item (...)     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.memcache.AsyncMemcacheServiceImpl$7.transform(AsyncMemcacheServiceImpl.java:557)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.memcache.AsyncMemcacheServiceImpl$7.transform(AsyncMemcacheServiceImpl.java:544)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceApiHelper$RpcResponseHandler.convertResponse(MemcacheServiceApiHelper.java:58)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceApiHelper$1.wrap(MemcacheServiceApiHelper.java:103)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceApiHelper$1.wrap(MemcacheServiceApiHelper.java:98)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.wrapAndCache(FutureWrapper.java:56)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:93)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:89)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.quietGet(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:26)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.put(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:74)
>     at
>   ...

Subsequent Message:

> After handling this request, the process that handled this request was
>   found to have handled too many sequential errors, and was terminated.
>   This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request
>   to your application. If you see this message frequently, you are
>   likely returning errors continously from your application.

**NOTE:** The object I am storing has only 2 string fields.

Could any of you let me know what could the reason? Also when does appengine emit the message?

Comment: Stack trace would be very useful